# Fixing Archive Annoyances with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have recently become annoyed enough with something about the linux command line experience to take action.

I welcome all comments, but specific things I'd like input on are:

- Is there something already available that does this?
- How would you do the same thing in Perl or Python?
- How would you go about reducing code duplication here? (The file-types hash looks similar enough in both places that it feels like I should be able to abstract it)
- In `unpack`, is there a better way of determining file-type?
- Can you think of any situations that would cause `pack` to blow up (and any ways of solving those situations)? Just failing to do anything wouldn't be *too* bad, but (for example) compressing random other files is something I'd like to avoid.

  ---

Take 4:

`unpack`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

archive_types = { 
  "tar"     => ["tar", "-xvf"],
  "tar.gz"  => ["tar", "-zxvf"],
  "tgz"     => ["tar", "-zxvf"],
  "tar.bz2" => ["tar", "-jxvf"],
  "rar"     => ["unrar", "x"],
  "zip"     => ["unzip"]
}

ARGV.each do |target|
  file_type = target.match(/\.([^\W0-9]{3}?(\.\w+)?)$/)[1]
  if archive_types[file_type]
    args = archive_types[file_type].push target
    system(*args)
  else
    puts "Dunno how to deal with '#{file_type}' files"
  end
end
```

`pack` (with added `--exclude` options for my ease of use):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'optparse'
require 'pp'
require 'fileutils'

archive_types = { 
  "tar"     => ["tar", "-cvf"],
  "tar.gz"  => ["tar", "-zcvf"],
  "tgz"     => ["tar", "-zcvf"],
  "tar.bz2" => ["tar", "-jcvf"],
  "zip"     => ["zip"]
}

########## parsing inputs
options = { :type => "tar", :excluded => [".git", ".gitignore", "*~"] }
optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|
  opts.on("-e", "--exclude a,b,c", Array,
          "Specify things to ignore. Defaults to [#{options[:excluded].join ", "}]") do |e|
    options[:excluded] = e
  end
  opts.on("-t", "--type FILE-TYPE", 
          "Specify archive type to make. Defaults to '#{options[:type]}'. Supported types: #{archive_types.keys.join ", "}") do |t|
    options[:type] = t
  end
end
optparse.parse!
##########

ARGV.each do |target|
  if not archive_types[options[:type]]
    puts "Supported types are #{archive_types.keys.join ", "}"
    exit
  elsif options[:type] == "zip"
    exclude = options[:excluded].map{|d| ["-x", d]}.flatten
  else
    exclude = options[:excluded].map{|d| ["--exclude", d]}.flatten
  end
  args = archive_types[options[:type]] +
         [target + "." + options[:type], target] + 
         exclude
  system(*args)
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your `pack` and `unpack` scripts will fail if any of the targets contain spaces (or other shell meta-characters) in their name. Generally it's almost always a bad idea to insert arguments into commands using string interpolation.

I assume you're using backticks rather than `system` because you don't want the output of the invoked commands to go to the screen. In that case you can use `IO.popen`, which since ruby 1.9 can take an array as its first argument.

As a trivial sidenote: There doesn't seem to be any point in passing the `-v` flag to `tar` if you're not going to print its output, so I'd remove it.

Comment: Nope, just being an idiot. Now that I've had time to play, new versions using `system` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 3):

"Take 2" looks much nicer than the initial version.
One bug seems to be `"unrar"   => "unrar"`, which should be `"rar"   => "unrar"`.

Comment: Yup, caught that earlier; fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

I find take two (for unpack) to be harder to read, actually.  It's less extensible, for sure, but for a shell script, it's nice to be very explicit about what you're doing.